# loading two table data from odbc in one object qlikview

Tags: odbc, qlikview

I was trying to get data from two tables in db that I have connected through ODBC. not sure exactly how to do it because I was trying basic queries I learnt in db400.

```
ODBC CONNECT TO trial;

//-------- Start Multiple Select Statements ------



SQL SELECT *

FROM graphdata.`kbl_one_voice_responsiveness_measured`;

//-------- End Multiple Select Statements ------



/*TARGET TABLE */



LOAD [setup],

    'Responsiveness' as Domain,

    [sku],

    [KPI],

    [target]

as [SQL SELECT *

FROM graphdata.`kbl_one_voice_responsiveness_target`;]
```

AND I'm getting this error

```
Syntax error



Unexpected token: 'ODBC', expected one of: ',', 'AutoGenerate', 'From', 'From_Field', 'Inline', 'Resident', 'Where', ...



LOAD [setup],

    'Responsiveness' as Domain,

    [sku],

    [KPI],

    [target]

as [SQL SELECT *

FROM graphdata.`kbl_one_voice_responsiveness_target`;]

///$tab KBL_Perf

>>>>>>ODBC<<<<<< CONNECT TO trial
```

please let me know where I'm going wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't wrap the sql select in `[]`

```
LOAD 
  setup,
  'Responsiveness' as Domain,
  sku,
  KPI,
  target
;
SQL 
SELECT 
  *
FROM 
  graphdata.`kbl_one_voice_responsiveness_target`
;
```

Also there is no need to wrap fields in `[]` unless they are containing spaces.

Comment: Thanks @Stefan it worked, if you could you explain," there is no need to wrap fields in [] unless they are containing spaces." like if I'm going to use two load statements from two different table in the same workspace then shouldn't I give []?

Comment: my point was that in your example you have `[sku], [KPI],` when loading the data (the QV part). QV dont mind having `[]` around the fields. but this can be skipped if the field name dont contain spaces. so in your case `[sku], [KPI],` = `sku, KPI,`. But if the fields were `sku, KPI Description,` you should wrap the second field in `[]` like `sku, [KPI Description],`

Comment: Thanks that helped. :)